# Using xpath and selenium the right way in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I will describe what I want to achieve first:

I have on a webpage multiple links and I am looping through wach one by using:

```
for link in dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href'):
    FINAL_URL = urlparse.urljoin(url, link)
```

On each of these pages I have to press a specific link, which is always positioned at the same position:

```
my_page = '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href'

    for link1 in dom1.xpath(my_page):
    # more code to go
```

If that link is starting with `http` I want to open it using **selenium**, search for a form which might have different selectors on each page, and press a submit button:

```
for link1 in dom1.xpath(my_page):
        if link1[:4] == 'http':
            driver.get(link1)
            inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@*[contains(., 'name')]]")
            inputElement.send_keys("somename")
            inputElement1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@*[contains(., 'email')]]")
            inputElement1.send_keys("email@yahoo.com")
            inputElement1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
```

Now, when I am running the above code, I get:

```
line 38, in <module>  
inputElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input​[@*[contains(., 'name')]]")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 707, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException
```

My full code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urlparse
import lxml.html



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


URL = 'http://example.com'
dom = lxml.html.parse(URL)
url = dom.docinfo.URL
BASE = dom.find('head/base')
EMPTY = ''

if BASE:
    url = BASE.get('href', url)

for link in dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href'):
    FINAL_URL = urlparse.urljoin(url, link)

    dom1 = lxml.html.parse(FINAL_URL)
    my_page = '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href'

    for link1 in dom1.xpath(my_page):
        if link1[:4] == 'http':
            driver.get(link1)
            inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@*[contains(., 'name')]]")
            inputElement.send_keys("cevanume")
            inputElement1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@*[contains(., 'email')]]")
            inputElement1.send_keys("email@yahoo.com")
            inputElement1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong and how can I prevent bad usage of `selenium` and `xpath` in the future ?

I will also be open to any constructive critics and improvements of the code.

Comment: What you want by "//input​[@*[contains(., 'name')]]". Will you please share the html  ?

Comment: I'd like to find the value `name` and `email` in the `input` tag. If one of these values is found, insert a value and press enter. The HTML is different from page to page and I had to find a common element. So the HTML is redundant.

Comment: Have you tried "//input[contains(@*, 'name')]]"

Comment: Yes, I tried. It can't find the element. The problem that I am facing is that each input can be different and I have to find a way of writing an `xpath` which will handle this

Comment: Take value 'name' as an example. <input foo='name' bar='other' />  **and** <input bar='name' foo='other' />   Both these two elements are what you want to handle. Am I correct?

Comment: Please share the HTML of a relevant section so we can help figure out how best to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanations and code fragments I figure, that on your site there is really only one input element for "email" and only one for "name"

And you want to find them by checking if they contain an attribute with the respective name, here's how you can do it:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@name]")
name.send_keys("cevanume")
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input​[@email]")
email.send_keys("email@yahoo.com")
```

Be aware that there are way better solutions, but without you sharing your HTML it's hard to give fitting advice...

Comment: He wants to handle the tag which has attribute **value**  'name' or 'email' instead of attribute **key**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a lot of InvalidSelectorException errors, it is absolutely worthwhile to work through some tutorials or find sites that provide simple examples to identifying HTML with xpath.

In general, you should understand the syntax and how to construct very basic expressions before writing from scratch, the same way that, if you were writing out math equations, you would need to understand what -+/*() mean and the order of operations. This will help you succeed on the first try and also know what questions you need to ask when you get stuck.

There are tons of tutorials, so find one that makes sense to you and work through it. [There are definitely a lot of xpath tutorials which provide examples useful for Selenium.](http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/introduction-to-selenium-automation/selenium-ide/115-selenium-ide-xpath-tutorials)

Because you did have specific xpaths expression you are trying to work out right now, and it's mostly just a matter of correcting the syntax:

```
//a/@href
```

The // and / represent nodes (the tags), and @s are attributes. The expression above will fail because @href is not a node inside the anchor tag. Attributes belong to nodes, and you must always give them a value:

```
//a[@href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"]
```

You also want to have as short expressions as possible to make an accurate match, so it is less brittle and less likely to fail if the HTML document changes slightly, so you don't have to necessarily go through all the //table/td/tr to get to the  tag.

e.g.

```
//div[@class="product_info"]//a
```

You also want to avoid using indexes like //tr[7] if attributes are possible, since less specific expressions are likely to return elements you don't want or not find any, unless your test is literally verifying what the very seventh tr tag in the document is and should always fail otherwise (this will not usually be what you want to do).

For your main question, which is about partial matching, here's some clarification of what @* can do and . can do, and how to use contains:

```
//input​[@*[contains(., 'name')]]
```

The nested bracket in this case is not valid xpath. To make this a valid xpath expression, write it like this

```
//input​[contains(@*, "name")]
```

That xpath should find any input tag that has any attribute with a value containing "name", like

```
<input something="name" somethingelse="anothervalue">
<input something="value" somethingelse="name">
```

but NOT input elements that contain "name" inside the tag, e.g.

```
<input>name</input>
```

If you want to find one OR the other with one expression, use "or"

```
//input​[contains(., "name") or contains(@*, "name")]
```

A lot of people prefer to use more simple and less brittle locators, because unexpected changes in the DOM can break xpath easily and there are always lots of those. So, find_element_by_id() or find_element_by_class() are great to use to be more flexible. You can also avoid xpath by using CSS locators, if you understand that syntax better.

Comment: I have already suggested **//input​[contains(@*, "name")]**. But the post owner said it doesn't work.

Comment: I still get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException` even when I try your method. I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: You need to provide an HTML sample, with your question then. You can't usually write an complex xpath without know what the document will look like. - If you can't, I hope the explanations of how to write valid xpath will help you later.